# Big React component with conditional rendering or smaller separate components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a specific question about coding practices for React.js.

I have two pages in my React application that render UI cards based on data returned from the backend. They are almost identical, except one has a UI for filter options and another has a search bar.

What would be the better way of structuring these two different pages and why?

`----------------`

**OPTION A** (one big component with conditional rendering)

`App.jsx`

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/page1" element={<Page showFilter=true showSearchBar=false />} />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<Page showFilter=false showSearchBar=true />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

`Page.jsx`

```js
function Page(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {props.showSearchBar && (<SearchBar />)}
      {props.showFilter && (<Filter />)}
      <ItemsList />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

`----------------`

**OPTION B** (two separate components with sub-component reuse)

`App.jsx`

```js
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/page1" element={<Page1 />} />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

`Page1.jsx`

```js
function Page1(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Filter />
      <ItemsList />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

`Page2.jsx`

```js
function Page2(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <SearchBar />
      <ItemsList />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

`----------------`

Of course the above list of options isn't exhaustive. If there are any other ways to solve this that might be more suitable for my task, I'd be happy to hear it.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `OPTION A` looks good. But you don't need to pass `showFilter` and `showSearchBar` as props. You can determine those values in `Page` component using `useLocation()` hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option C React Composition

### App.jsx

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/page1" element={<Page><Filter /></Page>} />
    <Route path="/page2" element={<Page><SearchBar /></Page>} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

### Page.jsx

```
function Page(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {props.children}
      <ItemsList />
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I think it'll depend on if the Page component needs to pass some props from it to either the Filter or Search components, then going through this approach might require some cloning and passing those props.

Answer (score 2):

I think option A seems fine also, at least until the UI start to differ significantly then you might have to go for option B.